# Weird behaviour with substring

Tags: c++

I'm writing an algorithm to decode base64. In the below code near the very end, if I change:

```
Binary.substr((FirstChar - 1) >= 0 ? (I - 1) : 0);
```

to

```
Binary.substr((I - 1) >= 0 ? (I - 1) : 0);
```

It throws `std::out_of_range`. However, if I leave it alone, it works fine..

The entire code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <algorithm>

static const std::string Base64Chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";

std::string DecodeBase64(std::string Data)
{
    std::string Binary = std::string();
    std::string Result = std::string();

    for (std::size_t I = Data.size(); I > 0; --I)
    {
        if (Data[I - 1] != '=')
        {
            std::string Characters = Data.substr(0, I);
            for (auto it = Characters.begin(); it != Characters.end(); ++it)
                Binary += std::bitset<6>(Base64Chars.find(*it)).to_string();
            break;
        }
    }

    for (std::size_t I = 0; I < Binary.size(); I += 8)
    {
        int FirstChar = I;
        std::string str = Binary.substr((FirstChar - 1) >= 0 ? (I - 1) : 0);
        Result += static_cast<char>(std::bitset<8>(str).to_ulong());
        if (I == 0) ++I;
    }

    return Result;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout<<DecodeBase64("aGVsbG8gdGhlcmUgbm9vYg==");
}
```

It is weird because I assigned `I` to `FirstChar` right before I call `substr` so it should be the same exact value.. Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because `I` is of type `std::size_t`, which is unsigned. When `I` is zero, `I - 1` is interpreted as a very large positive number.

Converting `I` to an `int` which happens in the assignment fixes the problem, because `FirstChar` is now *signed*, so `FirstChar -1` could become negative.

Converting `I-1 >= 0` to an equivalent `I >= 1` should fix this problem:

```
Binary.substr(I >= 1 ? (I - 1) : 0);
```

Comment: Omg.. signed vs. unsigned =(. Thank you! This indeed fixes it. I'll have to be more careful now.